# Getting Full Output of System Log (Terminal)

Tags: java, console, terminal, logging

I am making a console Java app where you can type in console commands like Terminal on Macintosh/Ubuntu/Windows Command Prompt and then it outputs it to a log.

I was wondering, when executing a system/console command, how I get the results/log from that command?

Note: I mean literal code + explanation please.

Comment: Do you mean: like the standard output?

Comment: What's wrong with `System.out.println(results)`?

Comment: For example utility prints current date: `public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(new Date());
 }`

Comment: Oh, I see, you want something like [`popen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) -- but for Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, the easiest is this (or a variant), from [this example](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/ReadFromCommand.html).

```
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
InputStream in = child.getInputStream();
```

If you have internal commands you'd like to go to two places, consider something like a [Commons IO TeeOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html).

You could combine the above techniques to get all output, whether from internal or external commands, to both your console, and a "shadow" log file.

Comment: @GrayAdams I don't understand your comment; sorry.